# TypeScript and HTML Buttons without angular or react possible?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am very new to Typescript, and want to make a small login page using Typescript. I have already transpiled the .ts code to .js, but the buttons still do not function.

Sadly there are not any tutorials on this without angular or react for TypeScript, and I am very confused on how to move forward.

**Currently, I have the buttons working as simple as possible: all they are supposed to do right now is call an alert**

I was wondering why that is and where my code is wrong. Everything builds well and there are no errors given when I compile.

> this is my .ts code

```
interface LoginInfo{
    username: string;
    password: string;
}
class LoginTs{
    username: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(username: string, password: string ) {
        this.username=(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("se")).value;
        this.password=(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("sp")).value;
        

        let submitBtn= document.getElementById("enter")
        submitBtn.addEventListener("click",(e:Event) =>{ return loginTs.validateInput()});

        let forgotBtn= document.getElementById("forgotPass")
        forgotBtn.addEventListener("click",(e:Event) =>loginTs.validateInput());
    }

    validateInput(){
             return alert("wrong user or password but good job erin")
    }
    //validateInput(user:string, pass:string){
      //   if(user =="billy" && pass =="bronco1"){
      //       alert("success")
      //   }
      //   else{
      //       alert("wrong user or password but good job erin")
      //   }
  //  }
}

let submit= document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
     let username = (document.getElementById("se") as HTMLInputElement).value;
     let password = (document.getElementById("sp") as HTMLInputElement).value;

    });


let loginTs = new LoginTs("billy", "bronco");
loginTs.validateInput();
```

> this is my HTML code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Capstone Typescript Login</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<header>
    <h2>Billy Bronco's Grading Calculator</h2>
</header>

<div id="container">

    <div id="tabs">

        <p id="lt" class="tabs" onclick="loginTabFun()">Log in</p>
        <p id="rt" class="tabs" onclick="regTabFun()">Register</p>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Login.css">

        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="cont">

        <div id="login" class="comm">
            <h3>Sign in</h3>

            <input id="se" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
            <input id="sp" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>

            <input type="button" class="button" id="enter" value="Login">
            <input type="button" class="button" id="forgotPass" value="Forgot Password?">

        </div>


        <div id="register" class="comm">
            <h3>Register</h3>

            <input id="re" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
            <input id="rp" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
            <input id="rrp" type="password" placeholder="Re write Password" required/>
            <input type="submit" onclick="register()" value="Submit"/>

        </div >


        <div id="forgot" class="comm">
            <h3>Forgot Password</h3>
            <div>
                <input id="fe" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
                <input type="submit" onclick="forgot()" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<script src="LoginTs.js"></script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

> this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "files" : ["../typings/tsd.d.ts", "<LoginTs.ts>"]
}
```

Thank you so much, once I understand how to do just get the basic button working, I think I'll be all set to move forward.

Comment: Hi, a simple way to test if your transpiled js file is attached correctly or not would be to put a simple alert("hi") in the file.
Did you try something like that ?

Comment: Did you check the javascript console for errors at runtime on click? `loginTs` might not be defined.

Comment: @NisanthReddy  it does not show the alert("hi") either, I checked where it is saved, and it is in the same folder as .html, so I don't understand why they don't work. I'm using Intellij as well and it compiles .ts nicely into .js

Comment: There are many resources on how to add a click event handler to a button. This isn't specific to typescript.

Comment: Hi @ErinB. If alert doesnt work then the issue is definitely with ts. Check if you are transpiling correctly and whether your folder structure is correct.

Comment: @AndyRay I was able to make one in a previous project with just JavaScript, so it is weird to me why it is not working for my typescript project specifically. Many tutorials are using angular and react and I want o do it without importing those. there are no JavaScript errors at runtime on click.

Comment: I think you need to do additional debugging of your code either using the chrome step through debugger, or with console.log to see what code is firing. It should be simple to figure out which code path isn't getting executed.

Comment: @NisanthReddy I just added my tsconfig.json, could that probably be the issue? i added "files" but do I need to have an include?

Comment: @ErinB added an answer, check if that fixes the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to run your files and you seem to have 3 minor issues.

1. Null pointer error - There is no element with the id `submit`. So the `document.getElementById("submit")` in your code is giving a null which when used to call `addEventListener` is throwing an error. This can be seen in the chrome console.
2. In your html code, you have set `onClick` parameter as `register()` and `forgot()`, whereas they should just be `register` and `forgot` like this 
    `<input type="submit" onclick="forgot()" value="Submit"/>`
3. In your tsconfig, instead of `"<LoginTs.ts>"` it should just be `"LoginTs.ts"`.

Fixing these 3 points should be enough for you to get it up and running. tsconfig is all correct. no issues with that.